# Union or Variant type static dispatch

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a function which takes a number of arguments, each of which may be one of a set of types.

I can handle this dynamically and throw a type error if it fails, as in the code snippet directly below but I would much rather catch these type errors at compile time.

```vb
Function specializingFunction(a) As String
    Select Case a.GetType
        Case GetType(Integer)
            Return "INT"
        Case GetType(Boolean)
            Return "BOOL"
        Case Else
            Return "__UNKNOWN__"  ' or throw an exception
    End Select
End Function

Sub mayFail(a1, a2, a3, a4)
    Console.WriteLine(specializingFunction(a1))
    Console.WriteLine(specializingFunction(a2))
    Console.WriteLine(specializingFunction(a3))
    Console.WriteLine(specializingFunction(a4))
End Sub
```

I had hoped to solve this problem using dotNET generics, see the final code example in this question.

I am happy to use either:
   1. an open solution - client code may add further type specializations as in the c++ code below
   2. a closed solution - a fixed set of allowed types, as could be acheived with algebraic data types in (e.g.) Haskell or boost::variant in C++

...but I would be interested to hear answers for both.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string specializedFunction(bool x)
{
   return string("BOOL");
}


std::string specializedFunction(int x)
{
   return string("INT");
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void correctlyResolves(T1 a1, T2 a2, T3 a3, T4 a4)
{
   cout << specializedFunction(a1) << "\n";
   cout << specializedFunction(a2) << "\n";
   cout << specializedFunction(a3) << "\n";
   cout << specializedFunction(a4) << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    correctlyResolves(1, true, 3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Haskell example

```
data X = XInt Int | XBool Bool

descriminator :: X -> String  
descriminator (XInt  a) = "INT: " ++ show a
descriminator (XBool a) = "BOOL: " ++ show a


lottaArgs :: X -> X -> X -> X -> IO ()
lottaArgs a b c d = do 
                     putStrLn $ descriminator a
                     putStrLn $ descriminator b
                     putStrLn $ descriminator c
                     putStrLn $ descriminator d

main = lottaArgs (XInt 1) (XBool False) (XInt 2) (XInt 3)
```

The solution that I tried is the one below, however is appears VB attempts to instantiate the function in its generic form (without knowing the types T1 - T4). VB therefore gives the errors of the form "Value Type 'T1' cannot be converted to 'Integer'".

```vb
Function specializedFunction(a As Boolean) As String
    Return "BOOL"
End Function

Function specializedFunction(a As Integer) As String
    Return "INT"
End Function

Sub failsHorribly(Of T1, T2, T3, T4)(a1 As T1, a2 As T2, a3 As T3, a4 As T4)
   Console.WriteLine(specializedFunction(a1))
   Console.WriteLine(specializedFunction(a2))
   Console.WriteLine(specializedFunction(a3))
   Console.WriteLine(specializedFunction(a4))
End Sub

Sub Main()
   failsHorribly(1, True, 3, 4)
End Sub
```

How best can I solve this sort of design problem in VB? Is there any appropriate statically-verified union or variant type?

I guess I could create a custom type with an `Object` member which can only be constructed with one of the allowed types, but this does not seem very elegant, there must be a better way.

### Edit: Solution

See my answer below for an implementation of a wrapper-object based solution

Comment: I would probably go with the wrapper type. Instead of forcing the user to call the type's constructor, you could provide implicit conversion operators.

Comment: Your generic attempt fails because a generic function has to be usable for any valid types supplied at runtime - the same IL code has to be usable for any type. This is the opposite of C++ templates which are resolved at compile time.

Comment: Since .NET generics function fundamentally different from C++ templates, an equivalent solution simply doesn’t exist. Your workaround isn’t too bad. I’m fairly confident that no generic (= configurable list of allowed types) type-safe solution exists. However, it would be appreciated if you could write your solution *as an answer* rather than as an edit in the question. That way it’s more visible for others with a similar problem. As a bonus, you can collect upvotes for the answer. ;-)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - done, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a solution with a custom type which provides conversions in both directions in order to allow me to use it for `ByRef` arguments.

It's pretty verbose, but I think verbosity is a major design goal of VB :¬)

It's also not perfect as it still does not statically keep track of the argument type and therefore provides conversions to every possible contained type irrespective of what it's actual type is.

I may have a look at using generics on top of this to help with this.

Below is an implementation of this technique on the toy Int/Bool example I have been using for this question:

```vb
Class AllowedArgs
    Private a_ As Object  ' can't declare a_ as a reference
    '
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    '
    Public Sub New(ByRef s As Integer)
        a_ = s
    End Sub
    '
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(a As Integer) As AllowedArgs
        Return New AllowedArgs(a)
    End Operator
    '
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(a As AllowedArgs) As Integer
        If TypeOf a.a_ Is Integer Then
            Return CType(a.a_, Integer)
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Operator
    '
    Public Sub New(ByRef s As Boolean)
        a_ = s
    End Sub
    '
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(a As Boolean) As AllowedArgs
        Return New AllowedArgs(a)
    End Operator
    '
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(a As AllowedArgs) As Boolean
        If TypeOf a.a_ Is Boolean Then
            Return CType(a.a_, Boolean)
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Operator
    '
    Public Overrides Function toString() As String
        Select Case a_.GetType()
            Case GetType(Integer)
                Return "INT: " + a_.ToString
            Case GetType(Boolean)
                Return "BOOL: " + a_.ToString.ToUpper
            Case Else
                Return "__THIS_SHOULD_NEVEN_HAPPEN__"
        End Select
    End Function
    '
    Public Sub setFromString(a As String)
        Select Case a_.GetType()
            Case GetType(Integer)
                Try
                    a_ = Integer.Parse(a)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    a_ = 0
                End Try
            Case GetType(Boolean)
                a_ = If(a.ToUpper = Boolean.TrueString.ToUpper, True, False)
            Case Else
                Console.WriteLine("__OH_DEAR_THIS_SHOULD_NEVER_HAPPEN__")
        End Select
    End Sub
    '
End Class

Sub actuallyWorks(ByRef a1 As AllowedArgs, ByRef a2 As AllowedArgs, ByRef a3 As AllowedArgs, ByRef a4 As AllowedArgs)
    ' this works just fine:
    Console.WriteLine(a1.toString())
    Console.WriteLine(a2.toString())
    Console.WriteLine(a3.toString())
    Console.WriteLine(a4.toString())
    ' these modifications are passed back correctly
    a1.setFromString("9999")
    a2.setFromString("9999")
    a3.setFromString("9999")
    a4.setFromString("9999")
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim a1 As Integer = 1
    Dim a2 As Integer = 2
    Dim a3 As Boolean = True
    Dim a4 As Integer = 3
    actuallyWorks(a1, a2, a3, a4)
    Console.WriteLine("After: " + a1.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("After: " + a2.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("After: " + a3.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("After: " + a4.ToString)
    Console.In.ReadLine()
End Sub
```